# C# String Format Placeholders in Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, formatting

I have a regular expression, defined in a verbatim C# string type, like so:

```
private static string importFileRegex = @"^{0}(\d{4})[W|S]\.(csv|cur)";
```

The first 3 letters, right after the regex line start (^) can be one of many possible combinations of alphabetic characters.

I want to do an elegant String.Format using the above, placing my 3-letter combination of choice at the start and using this in my matching algorithm, like this:

```
string regex = String.Format(importFileRegex, "ABC");
```

Which will give me a regex of `^ABC(\d{4})[W|S]\.(csv|cur)`

Problem is, when I do the String.Format, because I have other curly braces in the string (e.g. `\d{4}`) String.Format looks for something to put in here, can't find it and gives me an error:

```
System.FormatException : Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
```

Anyone know how, short of splitting the strings out, I can escape the other curly braces or something to avoid the above error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this (notice the double curly braces):

> `@"^{0}(\d`**`{{4}}`**`)[W|S]\.(csv|cur)"`

Comment: What he said plus this question also covers it and the answer has an MSDN link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160742/how-do-you-put-and-in-a-format-string

Comment: I always forget about the double curly braces. +1.